# WPF автоматическое изменение регистра текста в textBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Я хочу сделать так чтобы при введении текста в текстбокс первая буква всегда переводилась в верхний регистр. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Какое событие или по возможности пример кода

Answer (score 2):

Подключаем пакет `Expression.Blend.Sdk`.
Пишем поведение для `TextBox`.

```
public class TextBoxUpperCaseBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AssociatedObject.Text))
        {
            var firstChar = AssociatedObject.Text[0];
            if (char.IsLower(firstChar))
            {
                var selectionStart = AssociatedObject.SelectionStart;
                var upperFirstChar = char.ToUpper(firstChar);
                var stringTail = AssociatedObject.Text.Substring(1, AssociatedObject.Text.Length - 1);
                AssociatedObject.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", upperFirstChar, stringTail);
                AssociatedObject.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Подключаем поведение к `TextBox` на форме.

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox.WPF"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TextBox>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:TextBoxUpperCaseBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
</Window>
```

Comment: Простите, а зачем для этого пакет Expression.Blend.Sdk ?

Comment: @Nikita, `Behavior<>` там определён, нет разве?

Comment: с установленным Blend, который поставляется в комплекте с Visual Studio нужно только зареференсить сборку System.Windows.Interactivity, где и определены классы Behavior и Behavior<T>.

Comment: @Nikita, а если blend не установлен?)

Answer (score 1):

Разметка:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1"
         TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Код:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text != null && TextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpperInvariant() + TextBox1.Text.Substring(1);
}
```

Либо, если используется привязка к некоторому свойству, например, `Name`:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        name = value;
        if (name != null && name.Length > 0)
            name = name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpperInvariant() + name.Substring(1);
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать стили:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Lower"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

оригинал ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19406110/7099599

Comment: Не сработает, если вставить сразу несколько символов или если что-то ввести в начале поля при не пустом поле.